# I Need Help Setting Up a Back-End Infrastructure for my Future DApp

Tags: eosjs, javascript, api, blockchains

I'm going through the process of designing a desktop DApp. I'm going to use GraphQL API's to connect the EOS blockchain to a Node.js server that'll use MongoDB with Electron.js and React.js on the front-end. I'm confident this will work, but I'm wondering about scaling. I'm at a loss about potential problems I might have if too many people are using the Game DApp.

Is there anything I'd have to run the server on? Right now, I'm running the server locally on my computer, but I'd imagine for a professional release, I'd need to use something else but I'm not sure what that would be. I was looking at paid services like Amazon AWS and Microsoft Azure which is free for a year, but I preferred a free, open-source solution if there is one. Or at least one that won't cost a ton if the DApp really takes off.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there is no free, open-source honey.

You can start with small EC2 instance on Amazon AWS (even with "free" one) and scale up when you need it. So you will not pay a ton until you actually have some load.